# How can I replicated this folder setup from GitHubBrowser sample?

Tags: android-studio

I have been trying to learn more about unit and UI testing. During my progress I stumble upon this famous github [repo](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) that google uses to sample an app using archicture component. As I am new to all this, I am trying to learn and adapt this repo to my project.

I am stuck on how to set the folder as they do it. I believe I don't have to do exactly as they are doing, but learn how to do it I think it is part of my progress as Android developer.

So, I have few questions:

[How can I create a folder like this? I tried several ways, but in the end I dont know how they managed to put a kotlin file inside of it. I cannot add anything there, but they somehow managed to do it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnoQ7.png)

[How can I add a folder like this? All my attempts have gone wrong, I tried to add a java folder, directory, android resource folder. Nothing worked, I cannot add kotlin files. I would like to know how to make a folder like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQNB1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumble upon the same topic and wonder what is going on.

The first picture, a file inside the release folder. To be able to manipulate them you have to change the build variant to "release" in your Android Studio (left bottom corner).

As for the other picture, to create a file inside the path src/debug/.. you have o create a java folder "New > Folder (down below the option) > Java folder", then pick source Set Debug.

Answer (score 0):

for folder :-(com.android.example.github.testing) just right click on java then goto new then package and enter the folder name.
and for kotiln file:- just right click on created folder(com.android.example.github.testing) goto new then kotile file/class click on it.

Comment: Hi, Rishi, as shown in the first image this option is not available.

Comment: ok bro, i think this is a new activity created which name is OpenforTesting . you have to just goto new activity choose a new activity like:- Empty Activity, login Activity or other. and click on it after this you will see down there is source language is java you just change into kotiln option i think it will solve

Comment: thank you for your help. I figure it out.
For the debug, I have to create a java folder New > Folder > Java folder, then pick source Set Debug.
And the other one, I think it is just a useless folder in the directory.